# Run query and see the results on Java GUI

Tags: mongodb

I'm working on a school project. I want to create a program that User able to input the query on the GUI.

For example, if the following command is entered, the program should verify the query and return the result.

```
db.bios.find( { name: { first: 'John', last: 'McCarthy' } } )
```

I want some suggestions of how to verify the query and how  should I pass the query into the Database.

Comment: What do you mean, "verify the query"?

Comment: like type error or invalid query.

Comment: Send it to the database. Get data back - good query and you have data. Get an error back - you have invalid query.

Comment: I see. Then how should I send it to the database. I read it in as string. how do I treat the "query", convert it to doc?

Answer (score 1):

The Java MongoDB driver provides the [`JSON.parse`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.4/com/mongodb/util/JSON.html) utility function to parse a JSON string into a `DBObject`.

```java
import com.mongodb.util.JSON;
String json = "{ name: { first: 'John', last: 'McCarthy' } }";
DBObject query = (DBObject) JSON.parse(json);
DBObject result = db.bios.find(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the Jongo driver : http://jongo.org/

We use it like this :

```
Mongo mongo = new Mongo(/*host, port*/);
DB db = mongo.getDB(dbname);
Jongo jongo = new Jongo(db);

User user = jongo.getCollection("users").findOne(" { name: { first: 'John', last: 'McCarthy' }).as(User.class);
```

But as you see, it does not validate the full request : only the parameters of findOne() method. And Jongo is known as **the closest** driver to the shell.

In other terms I doubt that your exercise is easy to do in Java. Maybe you can find a "shell driver" in python, then java talks to python....

Comment: Thanks. SO there is no easy way to parse the query from the GUI to the Database?